# How to convert a Node object to an XML String without escaping CDATA nodes value?

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm using groovy.util.Node to manipulate tree structures and than I store the trees in XML format.

Some node value need to not be escaped.

Code to create a tree:

```
def nodeValue = '<![CDATA[you&me]]>'
Node rootNode = new Node(null, 'parent', [:], nodeValue)
rootNode.append(new Node(null, 'child', [:], nodeValue))
```

I've tried with  XmlUtil.serialize

```
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(rootNode) // & escaped to &amp;
```

Here's the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><parent>&lt;![CDATA[you&amp;me]]&gt;  <child>&lt;![CDATA[you&amp;me]]&gt;</child>
</parent>
```

And with XmlNodePrinter:

```
def sw = new StringWriter()
new (new IndentPrinter(sw, '', false)).print(rootNode)
println sw.toString()  // & escaped to &amp;
```

And the output:

```
<parent>&lt;![CDATA[you&amp;me]]&gt;<child>&lt;![CDATA[you&amp;me]]&gt;</child></parent>
```

Someone has a groovy solution for avoid CDATA escaping ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `StreamingMarkupBuilder` with `mkp.yieldUnescaped`:

```
import groovy.xml.*

String xml = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    def nodeValue = { ->
        mkp.yieldUnescaped '<![CDATA[you&me]]>'
    }
    parent {
        nodeValue()
        child {
            nodeValue()
        }
    }
}

assert xml == '<parent><![CDATA[you&me]]><child><![CDATA[you&me]]></child></parent>'
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I use StreamingMarkupBuilder to edit (adding a new Node) to an existing tree in a Node object ?

Comment: My goal is to insert a node in a existing XML file and keep unescaped its value.

Comment: OK I accept your answer and rewrite my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836237/editing-an-xml-string-with-groovy