# Editing an XML String with Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

- I have a string that contains XML data.
- I need to insert a new node as child of a specific node (I know 'id' attribute of the parent)
- The new node value must be unescaped when i print the new xml data.

code:

```
String xmlSampleToEdit = '''
<sample>
  <items>
    <one id="1">ONE</one>
    <ten id="10">TEN</ten>
    <twenty id="20"></twenty>
  </items>
</sample>
'''
String newNodeValue = 'twenty&one' //to keep unescaped !!!!
String newNodeName = 'twentyone'
String parentNodeId = '20'

String ExpectedResult = '''
<sample>
  <items>
    <one id="1">ONE</one>
    <ten id="10">TEN</ten>
    <twenty id="20">
       <twentyone>twenty&one</twentyone>
    </twenty>
  </items>
</sample>
'''
```

This kind of nodes will contain data that will be processed (not for displaying HTML pages) so if it's escaped processing will break.

Is it possible to insert the new node with StreamingMarkupBuilder and mkp.yieldUnescaped
if I don't know the XML content ?

Any other solution ?

Comment: A node value such as `twenty&one` is not allowed. You cannot have unescaped ampersands in XML documents.

Comment: also, why do you want to keep it unescaped? just so you read it correctly? what isn't processing the value correctly that is forcing you to unescape it? the point of the escaped data is that it will read back correctly by a target system.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code to parse the XML text in Groovy as a tree node.

```
def rootNode = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlSampleToEdit) 
def node = rootNode.items.'*'.find { node->
    node.name() == 'twenty' && node.@id == '20'
}
```

Next is code to create a new node as child to the node named "twenty":

```
def newNode = new groovy.util.Node( node, newNodeName )
newNode.setValue(newNodeValue)
```

To serialize the XML back to text you can use *XmlNodePrinter* or *XmlUtil.serialize()*.

```
def xmlOutput = new StringWriter()
def xmlNodePrinter = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(xmlOutput))
xmlNodePrinter.with {
    preserveWhitespace = true
    expandEmptyElements = true
    quote = "'" // Use single quote for attributes
}
xmlNodePrinter.print(rootNode)
def output = xmlOutput.toString() 
println output
```

This escapes the "twenty&one" text content because otherwise it would not be a valid XML document. The [XML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax) states that "the ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters...if they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped".

```
<sample>
  <items>
    <one id='1'>ONE</one>
    <ten id='10'>TEN</ten>
    <twenty id='20'>
      <twentyone>twenty&amp;one</twentyone>
    </twenty>
  </items>
</sample>
```

If want to print it unescaped then can simply replace "&amp" to "&" when printing it.

```
println output.replaceAll("&amp;", "&")
```

This would output the expected result:

```
<sample>
  <items>
    <one id='1'>ONE</one>
    <ten id='10'>TEN</ten>
    <twenty id='20'>
      <twentyone>twenty&one</twentyone>
    </twenty>
  </items>
</sample>
```

For more details on processing XML in Groovy see http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html